Can not scale raster image by dragging
For the fifth night now I have not been able to solve the problem of scaling a raster in a paperjs using drag.
The problem is that the scaling works fine in the positive direction, but not in the opposite direction! Help me please!
As an example, I created a sketch for two corners: you need to drag from the bottom-right corner to the opposite (top-left). Until the scale (x or y) is 0, everything works well, and then it breaks. Is there anyone who can help?
I'm doing the calculations wrong somewhere, but I can't find where...
var url = 'http://assets.paperjs.org/images/marilyn.jpg';
var raster = new Raster(url);
var hitResult,item;
var option = {
    bounds:true
}
var tool = new paper.Tool();
    tool.onMouseDown = function (event) {
            hitResult = paper.project.hitTest(event.point, option);

            if (hitResult) {

                item = hitResult.item;
              
                   item.selected = true;

            } 

        }

        tool.onMouseDrag = function (event) {
            if (hitResult) {
                if (hitResult.type == 'bounds') {
                    
var bottomRightCorner = item.bounds.bottomRight;
var oppositeCorner = item.bounds.topLeft;

                    var origSize = bottomRightCorner.subtract(oppositeCorner);


                    bottomRightCorner = bottomRightCorner.add(event.delta);
                   
                    var size = bottomRightCorner.subtract(oppositeCorner);

                    sx = size.x / origSize.x;
                    sy = size.y / origSize.y;

                    item.scale(sx, sy,oppositeCorner);


                
                } else {
                    //Used for moving a raster
                    item.position.x += event.delta.x;
                    item.position.y += event.delta.y;
                }
            }
        }

        tool.onMouseUp = function (event) {}


